# Mercurial: hg pull --bookmark without adding other bookmarks?

Tags: mercurial

`hg pull --bookmark B1` also adds other bookmarks. Why? Is this a bug? Can it be disabled somehow? I only want to pull changesets for `B1`. I don't want to get the (very many very old) bookmarks from ancestor changesets.

Comment: Where in the history are the other bookmarks which are getting pulled? Are then ancestors of the desired one?

Comment: Yes the other bookmarks are on old ancestor changesets already pulled much earlier.